# Нужно пройтись циклом по большому XML файлу (35GB) и забрать значения из определенного атрибута

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, парсер

Есть файл 35gb, в нём много разных значений, но мне нужны только те, что обозначены как "HOUSEGUID", в файле это выглядит так ([image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно пройтись циклом по файлу и в json файл внести значения HOUSEGUID. Т.е должен быть файл с строками 8a325764-2d72-44ad-9c39-4012ee04ada1 <-- такого кода.

Проблема в том, что файл большой и я боюсь что если даже получится написать такой код, то после запуска будет долгий процесс, поэтому было бы неплохо как-то видеть процесс (индикатор)

Comment: lxml умеет парсить XML-файлы по частям

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как я понимаю, файл слишком велик, а может быть и больше, поэтому предлагаю использовать генератор для чтения и очередь символов для сравнения.
Данный код протестирован мной на простом текстовом файле с кодировкой utf-8
но вы можете установить любую кодировку входного файла в коде.
Используйте обозначения кодировок [отсюда](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings).

К сожалению отображение прогресса обработки тут не реализовано.

```
import codecs
# https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

input_file = 'input_file.txt'
out_file = 'output.txt'


def get_line():
    with codecs.open(input_file, encoding='utf-8') as file:
        while True:
            yield file.read(1)


queue = ''
gen = get_line()
tag = 'HOUSEGUID="'
with open(out_file, 'w') as out_file:
    while True:
        char = next(gen)
        if not char:
            break
        queue += char
        if tag.find(queue) == 0:
            if queue == tag:
                # нашли то что надо
                queue = ''
                c = ''
                while True:
                    c += next(gen)
                    if c[-1] == '"':
                        c = c[0:-1]
                        out_file.write(c + "\r")
                        break
        else:
            queue = ''
```

Comment: Ваш вариант работает, однако если выбрать для output txt или json формат, то по ходу прохождения цикла и добавления новых строк в файлы - подходит лимит размера и операция прекращается, в таком случае, возможно ли прописать чтобы после того, как один файл output будет заполнен питон создавал новый и выгружал туда?

Comment: Не поверите, до сих пор идет цикл сканирования файла, запустил 8 часов назад, уже получено больше 1миллиона кодов, да, половина из них дублируется но не понятно как долго он будет ещё прогонять

Comment: Думаю добавлять контроль дублей при таком объёме - дело катастрофичное. По поводу отсечения файла - могу добавить вариант с этой опцией. Как закончилось сканирование? есть ли какие либо данные?

Comment: Максим, спасибо вам за помощь, сканирование закончилось через 48 часов. По итогу был получен XML файл размером 3гб. Всего было получено 83 миллиона необходимых значений. Если это былhttps://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1259682/Получение-значений-и-отправка-по-api?noredirect=1#comment2214479_1259682а первая задача, которую выполнял. Вторая тут решается --

Answer (score 2):

Я бы попробовал считать `XML` через [xml.sax](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/xml.sax.html). А прогресс можно показывать через [tqdm](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm).

- Для отображения прогресс бара, пока идет сбор `HOUSEGUID`, можно сделать через бесконечный итератор (`self.it`), тогда на каждый найденных элемент в XML будет обновлен прогресс бар
- Для скорости и возможности отслеживать прогресс сделал вручную сохранение в `JSON`
- Файл взял с сайта ФИАС, там только обновление (~172MB), т.к. не охото качать 10ГБ, а `sax` должен хорошо работать и с большими файлами. Кст, если убирать дубликаты `HOUSEGUID` их будет 148671, а так их в файле было 379708

  - Есть вероятность, что при заполнении `all_house_guid` памяти может не хватить, тогда код с записью файла JSON нужно перенести в `startElement`, накидал [пример-1](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/9cecdb8fdd8c341d8efc9f7c16a3aaa040ea6d8a/XML/sax_FIAS_with_progress__HOUSEGUID__no_collect.py#L15) и [пример-2](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/33456ec63dc6be4bc06652e953c72731246c0237/XML/sax_FIAS_with_progress__HOUSEGUID__no_collect__with_write_handler.py#L11) (в примерах уже нет множества для отсеивания дубликата, но вы можете сами это реализовать, заведя какой-нибудь кеш уникальных значений, например на 1000 элементов, новые значения будут вытеснять старые).

[Попробуйте:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/d755efb0415a6d9368ad0e2ab6b9cfb6146ce77c/XML/sax_FIAS_with_progress__HOUSEGUID.py#L17)

```
import xml.sax
from tqdm import tqdm


# В файле значения HOUSEGUID дублируются
all_house_guid = set()


class AttrHandler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def startDocument(self):
        self.it = iter(tqdm(iter(lambda: 0, 1)))

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if 'HOUSEGUID' in attrs:
            all_house_guid.add(attrs['HOUSEGUID'])

        next(self.it)


print('Сбор HOUSEGUID')

parser = xml.sax.make_parser()
parser.setContentHandler(AttrHandler())
parser.parse('AS_HOUSE_20210318_88f2df80-430a-400f-9373-da5b2c80e051.XML')

print(f'Найдено {len(all_house_guid)}')

print('Сохранение в JSON...')

with open('all_house_guid.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write('[')

    for i, guid in tqdm(enumerate(all_house_guid), total=len(all_house_guid)):
        if i > 0:
            f.write(',')
        f.write(f'"{guid}"')

    f.write(']')
```

Comment: Пробую ваш вариант, воткнулся с тем что Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a.berdnikov/Work/Data/fias_xml/HOUSEGUID.py", line 2, in <module>
    from tqdm import tqdm
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tqdm'

Comment: Как понимаю не установлен модуль, но установить через пайчарм или pip Install не выходит

Comment: Должно было сработать через `pip install tqdm`: https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#installation Убедитесь, что питон, в который вы устанавливаете и который вы запускаете один и тот же

Comment: `tqdm` вроде довольно неприхотлив, должен везде ставиться

Comment: Просто воткнулся в то, что в мак ос версия 2.7, а в пайчарме 3.9 и надо поменять, но ума не приложу что не так делаю. Уже 3 страницы гугла перерыл

Comment: @user435070, попробуйте так `pip3 install tqdm`, или `python3 -m pip install tqdm`, или откройте в PyCharm в настройках параграф интерпретатора, нажмите на `+` и выберите из списка `tqdm`, тогда `PyCharm` сам для той версии питона поставит библиотеку

Answer (score 1):

Ничего сложного:

- Открываете файл как обычный текстовый файл и читаете блоками какого-нибудь размера (я так понимаю переводов строки в вашем файле нет, поэтому так)
- В каждом блоке ищете регуляркой свой этот `HOUSEGUID`
- Сложность будет, когда искомый текст попадёт на стык двух блоков, поэтому, если не заморачиваться, проще всего будет хранить текущий буфер и предыдущий и искать шаблон в соединённом предыдущем и текущем буфере. Если вы знаете максимальный размер строки с вашим `GUID`, то от прошлой копии буфера достаточно будет взять только этот максимальный размер минус 1 символ, а не весь буфер.
- Чтобы не было повторений из-за двойного буфера нужно хранить множество с найденными в очередной порции GUID-ами и те, которые повторяются не писать в выходной файл, а остальные писать. Хотя если у вас есть точный размер искомой строки и вы обрезали буфер по методике предыдущего пункта, то это не нужно, повторов не будет.
- Прогресс можно выводить с помощью модуля `tqdm` в цикле чтения файла, но вам нужно будет сначала получить размер файла и указать его, иначе прогресс не получится точно отобразить

Если что-то непонятно, могу набросать конкретный код. Но приведите хотя бы один этот `GUID` целиком в виде текста в вопросе.