# Получение значений и отправка по API

Tags: python, xml, api

Есть значения из файла (output)
Каждое из значений необходимо подставить в API и полученный результат записать на выход

```
import codecs
from dadata import Dadata

input_file = 'output.XML'
out_file = 'address.XML'

def get_id():
    with open(r"output.XML", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            line = line.strip()
            ID = ('\"' + str(line) + '\"')
            with open(out_file, 'w') as out_file:
                while True:
                    token = "e277bc42a2d2df54feb153d6e79d66eb7f5daa50"
                    dadata = Dadata(token)
                    result = dadata.find_by_id("address", ID)
                    out_file.write(str(result) + "\r")
                    print(result)
                    print(ID)
```

Получилось вот так, но по итогу ничего не происходит

Comment: уточните, пожалуйста, что у вас в output.XML, в какое API и что вы подставляете,  какой ожидаемый результат?

Comment: https://github.com/hybrydtheory/fias_upload

Добавил репозеторий, в файле fias_upload показано как работает это API

Comment: Логика такова что у меня есть набор ID и я хочу получить адреса, чтобы все они записались в отдельный XML файл